# Why isn't my actionListener working?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am trying to make a button show up if I press the `hit` button, if `z==21`, but the button I'm trying to make show up is not showing up.  This is for a BlackJack game, but I pulled a little bit of code out of it, the part that isn't working.  Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;




public class blackjack {
// Creating static variables

        static JFrame frame = new JFrame("BlackJack");
        static JButton hit = new JButton("Get results");
        static int z = 21;
        static int y = 0;
        static JButton mainMenu = new JButton("Main Menu");
        static JButton status = new JButton("BUSTED!");
        static JButton status2 = new JButton("YOU WON!!!");
        static JTextArea words = new JTextArea("the number is " + z);


        static class Hit implements ActionListener{
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(z==21){
                status.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 500);
                status.setVisible(true);
                status.setBackground(Color.green);
                status.setText("The number is 21! it works!");
                } else {
                    status.setVisible(true);
                    status.setBackground(Color.RED);
                    status.setText("It doesn't work... more problems");
                    }
            }
        }



        public static void main (String[] args){
            //JFrame properties
            frame.setLayout(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            // Adding JVariables and setting bounds
            status.setBounds(20, 50, 500, 150);
            status2.setBounds(20, 50, 500, 150);
            hit.setBounds(5, 110, 300, 50);
            frame.add(hit);
            hit.setVisible(true);
            hit.setEnabled(true);
            hit.addActionListener(new Hit());

            words.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
            frame.add(words);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actionlistener works. But your button status is never add to the JFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Action Listeners should be added using `addActionListener` on things like buttons.  Your code doesn't even compile for me.

Comment: This `frame.add(hit);` fails because action listeners aren't components.

Comment: `hit` is a JButton.  `Hit` is an `ActionListener`.  The `ActionListener` is capitalized.